# To use STDBUF from Homebrew's coreutils

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I run `brew search stdbuf` and get

```
No formula found for "stdbuf".
Searching pull requests...
Closed pull requests:
coreutils: upstream fix for stdbuf (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/32955)
```

I run `brew install coreutils` but get `Warning: coreutils-8.23_1 already installed`.

I do but see no stdbuf in my system.

```
$ std [tab]
stdethers  stdhosts
```

My PATH is

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:
/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/masi/.cabal/bin
```

### Uninstall Macports

Using Macports and Homebrew together cause conflicts. 
Final solution is to uninstall Macports which is immature. 
Regardless of what your PATH is, Macports causes conflicts with programs in the PATH. 
I realised the core of the problem [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/232413/15504) at the end of the body about *How to Enlarge Disk Image in VirtualBox?*

---

How can you use stdbuf in OSX Yosemite?

Comment: Why do you have `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH` twice?

Comment: Not anymore when I combined export in `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`.

Comment: Can someone report this issue to homebrew? The stdbuf util should be in the standard path, while the libstdbuf.so shared lib should be in the libexec location.

Comment: What do you mean "MacPorts is immature"? MacPorts does have all GNU utils, they are just prefixed with a g, gls, gcp, gstdbuf etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to alter your path adding `coreutils` dir before `/usr/bin`. You can do something like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH
```

And should looks like the following after the changes:

```
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:
/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:
/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:
/Users/masi/.cabal/bin
```

After that, you must be able to use `stdbuf`.

Comment: My PATH is now `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/masi/.cabal/bin` after the change. I put the export to my `.bashrc`. There must be something else which is inserting the beginning to my PATH.

Comment: Did you source your `.bashrc` file from your `.bash_profile`? Check your PATH on `.bash_profile` too.

Comment: I had this `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH:$HOME/.cabal/bin` in `.bash_profile`. So I removed it in `.bash_profile` and added simply to `.bashrc` simply `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH:$HOME/.cabal/bin`.

Answer (score 15):

`coreutils` on OS X adds the prefix `g` to all the commands so as to not mess up with default programs on OS X.

It prints this when you run `brew install coreutils`

```
==> Caveats
All commands have been installed with the prefix 'g'.

If you really need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:

    PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

So unless you really need to use it as `stdbuf`, there is no real reason to update your path, you can simply run `gstdbuf` instead:

```
$ gstdbuf --help                                                         
Usage: gstdbuf OPTION... COMMAND
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess with your PATH and all you need is stdbuf:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s ../opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/stdbuf stdbuf
```

For whatever reason I also already had `coreutils` brewed, but only certain binaries linked - not remembering why, this seemed like the safest option

Comment: It would be great to understand why this linking is not done. I do not like putting too much in PATH and messing it up.